# One single logon for everything in web folder on web server?

Tags: php, apache

On my laptop (macOS with Homebrew) I have a webserver with several test and development sites and want to cloak a login aroumd it when the IP is other than localhost. I just want to make a single login.
I use Apache 2.4 and PHP 8.2 from Homebrew.
I know, Basic Authantication does work, but is insecure because the password is stored in plain text in a $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] variable. So I have a logon script.
In the .htaccess in the web root (/var/www/html) I have:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !(^\:\:1|127\.0)
RewriteRule ^.+$ "/login.php" [L,QSA]
```

which forces *any* webpage (even an image) on the web server to a login.
The login page contains:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/path/to/loginfunction.php");  // contains auth_login()
$userdata = array("user"=>"thisuser", "md5password" => md5("thispass"));
$ok = auth_login($userdata, 60); 

if ($ok) {
    header("Location: " .$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]);
    exit;
}
```

This however results in a redirect loop, because this php script redirects to the original page `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]` which in turn redirects to this script which is an infinite redirect loop.
The login function does not do any redirects. Even when I omot the login check and set $ok hard to `true`, the redirect loop persists.

How can I force Apache / PHP to redirect only once, i.e. when login succeeded, break out of redirect loop ? Setting a cookie is very insecure.

Comment: You can use basic auth and store the server side password hashed in a file which isn't accessible to the outside world. Apache supports this.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04 for example (instructions are similar for other operating systems, you can easy google it, and/or read the official apache docs- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html

Comment: Also why do you consider that a $_SERVER variable is insecure? It's only available in the server-side php code, for the lifetime of a request.